# In which unit is showed the accuracy using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

I'm using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function to get the current position of my phone.

It returns me a lot of information like latitude, longitude... And also the accuracy. I would like to know what's the unit that accuracy is using because I have no information about it,  it just return a number.

For example, I get returned `accuracy: 921`, are they meters? Are they miles? I don't find the documentation about it.

And I would like to know what could be the maximum valor of the accuracy, if a maximum exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accuracy is expressed in meters like it is described in **Mozilla Docs**:

> The Coordinates.accuracy read-only property is a strictly positive double representing the accuracy, with a 95% confidence level, of the Coordinates.latitude and Coordinates.longitude properties expressed in meters.

**source:**[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates/altitude](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates/accuracy)

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about the other last question?  I would like to know what could be the maximum valor of the accuracy, if a maximum exists

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai you are welcome.
The maximum valor of the accuracy, it is not fixed because it varies  **depending on many factors** like : the database of the API you uses to locate the IP and your device and other factors too ..
you can have a look to this articles explaining all:
[HTML5 Geolocation API – how accurate is it, really?](http://www.andygup.net/html5-geolocation-api-%E2%80%93-how-accurate-is-it-really/)
and also:
[How accurate (reliable) is IP GeoLocation](https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211035626-How-accurate-reliable-is-IP-GeoLocation-)

Comment: and if you want, you can see a nice explanation about accuracy too:
[How Accurate is HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-html5-geolocation-really-part-2-mobile-web/)

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!